# Convert factors into numeric while reading from a file without original values being lost

Tags: r, dataframe

Convert factors into numeric while reading from a file without original values being lost?

I used `as.character(as.numeric(x))` method, but `NA`s are introduced due to coercion. I need original numeric values to perform functions like mean, median etc.

Comment: Well is the column or columns numeric or factor?  You can't have both, and R's assigning NA to non numeric values is its way of dealing with this.

Comment: I think you have to try `as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Comment: Set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading the files, then set the classes to columns manually.